# Could Solr search contains wildcard in key?

Tags: solr, solrj, solr-search

I have a json block saved as one document in solr,

```
{
    "internal":...
    "internet":...
    "interface":...
    "noise":...
    "noise":...
}
```

Could I seach as " **inter*:*** "? I want to find out all content with key start with "inter"

Unfortunately, I got parser error, is there any way that I could the search with a wildcard in the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really. You'll have to do that as a `copyField` if providing a wildcard is important to you, in effect copying everything into a single field and then querying that field.

You can supply multiple fields through `qf` without specifying each field in the `q` parameter as long as you're using the `edismax` query handler - that's usually more flexible, but it will still require each field to be specified.

There's also a [little known feature named "Field aliasing using per-field `qf` overrides"](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#TheExtendedDisMaxQueryParser-Fieldaliasingusingper-fieldqfoverrides) (I'm wasn't aware with it, at least). If I've parsed what I've been able to find from a few web searches correctly, you should be able to do `f.i_fields.qf=internal internet interface&qf=i_fields`. In effect creating an `i_fields` alias that refers to those three fields. You'll still have to give them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dynamic fields`. It allow Solr to index fields that you did not explicitly define in your schema.

This is useful if you discover you have forgotten to define one or more fields. `Dynamic fields` can make your application less brittle by providing some flexibility in the documents you can add to Solr.

A dynamic field can be defined like

```
<dynamicField name="*_i" type="int" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

Please refer solr documentation for more on Dynamic Fields.
[Dynamic Fields](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/dynamic-fields.html)

After this create a copy field. Copy the dynamic fields into the copy field.

Once done with this, query can be done on the copyField.

```
<dynamicField name="inter_*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="internal_static" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="inter_*" dest="emp_static"/>
```